# Bone fracture cause

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles, bone-biology

I had bone fracture twice in the same arm. So I had first bone fracture in right forearm with 45 degree break on two bones, after 3 months of that fracture while I was climbing a slope I fell and I  used my two hands extended to stop kissing ground, I got hairline fracture in upper arm in middle on right arm again. Why left arm did not get fracture while right arm did, was it due to muscle loss I had incurred during first fracture or my bone became weaker in right arm after first fracture?

Comment: Its not off topic question is if muscles weakness happens or bone weakness happens after fracture in limb

Comment: the issue is the question is still medically liable, rewrite it to be less about your personal event and more about bone weakness due to fracture in general and it should be fine.